# Python Pandas compare values in multiple columns for partial duplicates and drop record

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a function/expression that compares multiple columns (`'Cust ID Count'`, `'Revenue'` and possibly `'Family Name'` for a record match and then keeps only the first record based on ascending order.  Also, this function will be looking at 2 different scenarios where there are multiple similar records:

1. Multiple records will match across all columns/series with the exception of `'street'` (records `0 & 1`)
2. Multiple records will match across all columns/series with the exception of `'street'` and `'Family Name'` (records `3 & 4`)

I realize it looks like we can only use `Cust ID` count and `Revenue` as the matching parameters, but I would also like to use `'family name'` as an option if possible.

Dataset:

```
 idx Cust ID Count    Family Name    street          Revenue
 0   10               Smith          spring          50 #match
 1   10               Smith          wilbur          50 #match
 2   45               Jerry          jane            35 #not a match
 3   25               Cole           mary            20 #match
 4   25               Stein          mary sue        20 #match
```

Output:

```
 idx Cust ID Count    Family Name    street          Revenue
 0   10               Smith          spring          50 #spring is kept due to alphabetical order
 1   45               Jerry          jane            35 #not a match
 2   25               Cole           mary            20 #mary is kept due to alphabetical order
```

Comment: the data is unclear, can we align it a little better?

Comment: what's your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(df.sort_values('Family Name')
 .drop_duplicates(['Cust ID Count', 'Revenue'], keep='first')
 .sort_index()
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or less elegant than Chris A's:

```
df1 = df[["Cust ID Count", "Revenue"]]
df1.sort_values(by=["Cust ID Count", "Revenue"])
diff1 = df1["Cust ID Count"].values[1:] - df1["Cust ID Count"].values[:-1] == 0
diff2 = df1.Revenue.values[1:] - df1.Revenue.values[:-1] == 0

eq = (diff1 == 0 & diff2)
eq = np.insert(eq, 0, True)
df[eq]
```